# How to troubleshoot when $wpdb-> update returns 0

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running the following query on my wordpress website

```
$error = $wpdb->update( $table_name, 
                        array( 'value' => $update_value ), 
                        array( 'lead_id' => $lead_id, 
                               'field_number' => 31.3 ), 
                        array( '%s' ), 
                        array( '%d', '%f' )
               );
```

It is intended to update gravity form entries after the user has initially submitted the form. This query runs fine for 24 fields but returns 0 for 2.

I have so far tried the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Storing the result as `$error` and running `var_dump($error);` after the query, it returns 0.
2. Running `var_dump( $wpdb->last_query );` immediately after the query to copy/paste the resulting SQL string into phpMyAdmin, which also reports 0 rows affected.
3. Manually selecting the row in phpMyAdmin using:
   `` SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_number` = 31.3 ``
   Which also returns no rows. However, I know that there are rows which match as I can se them in the table.
4. Manually selecting another field which updates as expected using the same query as above - this worked fine.
5. Changed the `$where_format` from `float` to `string`. No resulting change. Upon checking the db fields, the `field_number` field is stored as a float.
6. Used `$wpdb->prepare` to run a prepared query. Still no movement.
   Prepare statement as follows:

$error = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "
        UPDATE %s
        SET `value` = %s
        WHERE `lead_id` = %d AND `field_number` = %f
        ",
        $table_name, $update_value, $lead_id, 31.3
    )
);

Which, when `var_dumped` gives the following result:

```
string '
                    UPDATE prefix_rg_lead_detail
                    SET `value` = 'a:3:{i:0;s:9:\"Liverpool\";i:1;s:10:\"Manchester\";i:2;s:5:\"Leeds\";}'
                    WHERE `lead_id` = 4 AND `field_number` = 31.300000
                    ' (length=188)
```

I'm at my wits end now as I've tried everything I can possibly think of and still cant get 2 fields to update.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Because I weren't sure how to escape the backticks.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I've updated my original question with my results from using `$wpdb->prepare()`.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I've just tried to add images to try post to show you the table structure etc but I'm getting an error that the code is incorrectly indented. Here are the imgur links: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq4K0.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWlY9.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOaZb.png

Comment: The select is to see if any rows returns.

Comment: Your suggested `SELECT` statement returns no rows. The update statement returns `0 rows affected`. This is really weird. Pulling the data out of the DB works fine and that is based on field number too.

Comment: @JorgeCampos the result of `DESC prefix_rg_lead_detail` is this... http://imgur.com/a/DK3CG

Comment: The table is generated by the gravity forms WordPress plugin. Changing the data type may break the plugin. I’ll try out your suggestion and let you know how I get on. Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: @JorgeCampos I tried changing float to float(5,1) I'm still having the same issue. I have noticed that in the database, even though the column is named `field_number`, the keyname is `lead_field_number`. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I was trying to obfuscate some information incase, further down the line, some other DB details leaked in screenshots etc. when I've wrote `prefix_`, I've changed it from `wp_` myself.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Please see linked screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/VhMBw

Comment: No there is nothing to do with that. That means that your field `field_number` has an index on it and it is named `lead_field_number` and this index is of type BTREE. Try to run this query: `select * from prefix_rg_lead_detail where lead_id = 4 AND cast(field_number as DECIMAL(5,1)) = 31.3` and see if it returns result

Comment: @JorgeCampos That select worked perfectly fine. I ran ``UPDATE `prefix_rg_lead_detail` SET `value` = 'a:3:{i:0;s:9:\"Liverpool\";i:1;s:10:\"Manchester\";i:2;s:5:\"Leeds\";}' WHERE `lead_id` = 4 AND cast(field_number as DECIMAL(5,1)) = 31.3`` from phpMyAdmin too and that also worked great. I will see if I can figure out how to plug that into `$wpdb->update()`

Comment: I will prepare an answer for you then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final problem is indeed with the `FLOAT` type. It is an imprecise value, which is leading you to your problem. Although the database is showing the value `31.3` it most likely internally in the database is something like `31.30000000000001` which is why the `where` condition is not working. Take a look at the documentation here: [Problems with Floating-Point Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html).

So down the road lets go to the tests:

```
create table test (
   n float
);
insert into test values (31.3);

mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 31.3 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.17 sec)
```

Running a `select` statement on it with that value `31.3` will evaluate to nothing:

```
mysql> select * from test where n=31.3;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

There are a few ways you can solve it without changing the column type:

**1- Using the ROUND(field,number_of_decimals) function**

```
mysql> select * from test where round(n,2)=31.3;
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 31.3 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2- Casting it as DECIMAL type**

```
mysql> select * from test where cast(n as decimal(5,2))=31.3;
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 31.3 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in order to your update to work with this data you have to use one of those options in your update command like:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE %s 
                                 SET value = %s  
                               WHERE lead_id = %d 
                                 AND round(field_number,2) = %f ", 
                             $table_name, 
                             $update_value, 
                             $lead_id, 
                             31.3 ) 
            );
```

My recommendation is that you **change the field type**. AFAIK there is no situation where your plugin may break as of this change. What it may happens is a rounding value like you try to insert a value like `31.696` in a Decimal field of (6,2) it will became `31.67`. Also the difference is that the value of the field will be formatted as the decimals number you chose so `31.3` will start to apear as `31.30` You can change it as:

```
alter table yourTableName modify field_name DECIMAL(6,2);
```

Here are some test on that explanation:

```
mysql> alter table test modify column n decimal(10,2);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.90 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> select * from test;
+-------+
| n     |
+-------+
| 31.30 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test where n=31.3;
+-------+
| n     |
+-------+
| 31.30 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And to show the rounding:

```
mysql> insert into test values (31.696);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+-------+
| n     |
+-------+
| 31.30 |
| 31.67 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! Only issue I can see wiht your answer (although the cause has been identified and a working alternative has been suggested) is that the `WHERE` array within `$wpdb->update()` automatically puts the array keys in backticks, as in `'arrayKey' => someValue`. I believe this requires some custom SQL. I will comment said SQL when I have my functions updated!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you are indeed right. It should be the native version then. I will updated it.